# be aware of insert delete and update data into gridview in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, events, gridview, datagridview

I have a grid view that has a column called `Amount` .I have a `textbox` that shows the sum of `amount` column in `gridview` ,but i need to be aware when items in `gridview` are `inserted` `changed` and `deleted` because i need to update the `textbox`

Has anyone handled such a scenario. I would like to know which datagrid event I should be using,

I am using windows form application

Best regards

Comment: Use RowDeleted, RowUpdated, RowCreated events?

Comment: I am using windows form application not web form,i found row added and row removed but not row changed ?!!!

Comment: Sorry some reason I was thinking asp. You can use CellValueChanged

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of [RowsRemoved](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowsremoved%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [RowsAdded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowsadded%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [CellValueChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) events.

Comment: thanks ,could you please give me more details about CellValueChanged ,it means every cell in every row when changed this event is called?

Comment: @EA It fires whenever user edits any cell. I've updated msdn links see if that helps.

Comment: simply as @SriramSakthivel said just use those events and when they are fired, call the database and alter the data. ;)

Answer (score 2):

***Updated***

You can use these assuming your user is only adding and deleting 1 row at a time. also added a method with a linq statement to sum up your amount and assign it to the textbox.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex.Equals(dataGridView1.Columns["Amount"].Index))
    {
        UpdateTotal();
    }
}

private void dataGridView1_UserAddedRow(object sender, DataGridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    UpdateTotal();
}

private void dataGridView1_UserDeletedRow(object sender, DataGridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    UpdateTotal();
}

private void UpdateTotal()
{
    textBox1.Text = (dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
            .Sum(t => Convert.ToInt32(t.Cells["Amount"].Value))).ToString();
}
```